# working with stereo camera and rtabmap for 3d mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, stereo-camera, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am using rtabmap and a ZED stereo for this project based o,  3D mapping.
I have the following launch file, I tried to play with with it but no mapping :

```
<launch>

<arg name="rviz" default="false" />
   <arg name="rtabmapviz" default="true" />
   <arg name="local_bundle" default="true" />
   <arg name="stereo_sync" default="false" />
    
   <param name="use_sim_time" type="bool" value="True"/>
   
   <!-- Just to uncompress images for stereo_image_rect -->
   <node name="republish_left"  type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressed in:=/left/image_raw_color out:=/stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay" />
   <node name="republish_right" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressed in:=/right/image_raw_color raw out:=/stereo_camera/right/image_raw_throttle_relay" />

   <!-- Run the ROS package stereo_image_proc for image rectification -->
  
      <node pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" name="stereo_image_proc">
         <remap from="left/image_raw_color"          to="/stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay"/>
         <remap from="left/camera_info"              to="/stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="right/image_raw_color"         to="/stereo_camera/right/image_raw_throttle_relay"/>
         <remap from="right/camera_info"             to="/stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <param name="disparity_range"               value="128"/>
      </node>
      
      <node if="$(arg stereo_sync)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="stereo_sync" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync">
      <remap from="left/image_rect_color"   to="left/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect_color"   to="right/image_rect"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"   to="left/camera_info_throttle"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info"   to="right/camera_info_throttle"/>
    </node>
  
              
   <group ns="rtabmap">   
   
      <!-- Stereo Odometry -->   
      <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="stereo_odometry" name="stereo_odometry" output="screen">
         <remap from="left/image_rect"       to="/stereo_camera/left/image_rect"/>
         <remap from="right/image_rect"      to="/stereo_camera/right/image_rect"/>
         <remap from="left/camera_info"      to="/stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="right/camera_info"     to="/stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="rgbd_image_raw"        to="/stereo_camera/rgbd_image"/>
         <remap from="odom"                  to="/stereo_odometry"/>

         <param name="subscribe_rgbd"  type="bool" value="$(arg stereo_sync)"/>
         <param name="frame_id"        type="string" value="zed_camera_center"/>
         <param name="odom_frame_id"   type="string" value="odom"/>

         <param name="Odom/Strategy"      type="string" value="0"/> <!-- 0=Frame-to-Map, 1=Frame=to=Frame -->
         <param name="Vis/EstimationType" type="string" value="1"/> <!-- 0=3D->3D 1=3D->2D (PnP) -->
         <param name="Vis/MaxDepth"       type="string" value="0"/>
         <param name="Odom/GuessMotion" type="string" value="true"/>
         <param name="Vis/MinInliers"     type="string" value="10"/>
         <param unless="$(arg local_bundle)" name="OdomF2M/BundleAdjustment" type="string" value="0"/>
         <param name="OdomF2M/MaxSize"    type="string" value="1000"/> 
         <param name="GFTT/MinDistance"   type="string" value="10"/>
         <param name="GFTT/QualityLevel"  type="string" value="0.00001"/> 
         <param name="GFTT/QualityLevel"  type="string" value="0.00001"/>
      </node>
   
      <!-- Visual SLAM: args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->
      <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
         <param name="frame_id"         type="string" value="zed_camera_center"/>
         <param unless="$(arg stereo_sync)" name="subscribe_stereo" type="bool" value="true"/>
         <param name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="false"/>
         <param name="subscribe_rgbd"      type="bool" value="$(arg stereo_sync)"/>

         <remap from="left/image_rect"   to="/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color"/>
         <remap from="right/image_rect"  to="/stereo_camera/right/image_rect"/>
         <remap from="left/camera_info"  to="/stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="right/camera_info" to="/stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="rgbd_image_raw"        to="/stereo_camera/rgbd_image"/>

         <remap from="odom" to="/stereo_odometry"/>

         <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="30"/>
         <param name="map_negative_poses_ignored" type="bool" value="true"/>

         <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
         <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr"                   type="string" value="700"/>
         <param name="Grid/DepthDecimation"              type="string" value="4"/>
         <param name="Grid/FlatObstacleDetected"         type="string" value="true"/>
         <param name="Kp/MaxDepth"                       type="string" value="0"/>
         <param name="Kp/DetectorStrategy"               type="string" value="6"/>  
         <param name="Vis/EstimationType"                type="string" value="1"/>   <!-- 0=3D->3D, 1=3D->2D (PnP) -->
         <param name="Vis/MaxDepth"                      type="string" value="0"/>
         <param name="RGBD/CreateOccupancyGrid"          type="string" value="true"/>       
      </node>
      
      <!-- Visualisation RTAB-Map -->
      <node if="$(arg rtabmapviz)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd_gui.ini" output="screen">
         <param unless="$(arg stereo_sync)" name="subscribe_stereo"    type="bool" value="true"/>
         <param name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool" value="true"/>
         <param name="subscribe_rgbd"      type="bool" value="$(arg stereo_sync)"/>
         <param name="queue_size"          type="int" value="10"/>
         <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="zed_camera_center"/>
         
         <remap from="left/image_rect"  to="/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color"/>
         <remap from="right/image_rect"  to="/stereo_camera/right/image_rect"/>
         <remap from="left/camera_info"  to="/stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="right/camera_info" to="/stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle"/>
         <remap from="rgbd_image_raw"          to="/stereo_camera/rgbd_image"/>
         <remap from="odom_info"         to="odom_info"/>
         <remap from="odom"              to="/stereo_odometry"/>
         <remap from="mapData"           to="mapData"/>
      </node>
         
   </group>
  
   <!-- Visualisation RVIZ --> 
   <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/demo_stereo_outdoor.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

---

I GOT THIS FROM THIS TUTORIAL : http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorMapping

Next launch file is the camera drivers and all called zed_camera.launch in zed_ros_wrapper pkg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2018, STEREOLABS.


<launch>
    <arg name="camera_model"          default="0" /> <!-- 0=ZED, 1=ZEDM-->
    <arg name="svo_file"              default="" /><!-- <arg name="svo_file" default="path/to/svo/file.svo"> -->
    <arg name="zed_id"                default="0" />
    <!-- If a ZED SN is given, zed_id is ignored and the wrapper will specifically look for the ZED with the corresponding serial number -->
    <arg name="serial_number"         default="0" />     
    <arg name="verbose"               default="true" />

    <arg name="resolution"            default="2" /> <!--0=RESOLUTION_HD2K, 1=RESOLUTION_HD1080, 2=RESOLUTION_HD720, 3=RESOLUTION_VGA -->
    <arg name="frame_rate"            default="30" />
    <!-- RESOLUTION_HD2K   -> 2208*1242, available framerates: 15 fps.
         RESOLUTION_HD1080 -> 1920*1080, available framerates: 15, 30 fps.
         RESOLUTION_HD720  -> 1280*720,  available framerates: 15, 30, 60 fps.
         RESOLUTION_VGA    -> 672*376,   available framerates: 15, 30, 60, 100 fps. -->

    <!-- GPU ID-->
    <arg name="gpu_id"                default="-1" />

    <!-- Definition coordinate frames -->
    <arg name="publish_tf"                    default="true" />
    <arg name="pose_frame"                    default="map" />
    <arg name="odometry_frame"                default="odom" />
    <arg name="base_frame"                    default="zed_camera_center" />
    <arg name="left_camera_frame"             default="zed_left_camera_frame" />
    <arg name="left_camera_optical_frame"     default="zed_left_camera_optical_frame" />
    <arg name="right_camera_frame"            default="zed_right_camera_frame" />
    <arg name="right_camera_optical_frame"    default="zed_right_camera_optical_frame" />
    <arg name="imu_frame"                     default="imu_link" /> <!-- only used with ZED M -->

    <arg name="initial_pose"                  default="[0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0]" /> <!-- X, Y, Z, (meter) R, P, Y, (radians)-->

    <!-- Publish urdf zed -->
    <arg name="publish_urdf"                  default="true" />

    <arg name="camera_flip"                   default="false" />
    <arg name="rgb_topic"                     default="rgb/image_rect_color" />
    <arg name="rgb_info_topic"                default="rgb/camera_info" />
    <arg name="depth_topic"                   default="depth/depth_registered" />
    <arg name="depth_cam_info_topic"          default="depth/camera_info" />

    <node name="zed_wrapper_node" pkg="zed_wrapper" type="zed_wrapper_node" output="screen" required="true"><!-- launch-prefix="valgrind" -->

        <param name="camera_model"          value="$(arg camera_model)" />

        <!-- publish pose frame -->
        <param name="publish_tf"            value="$(arg publish_tf)" />

        <!-- flip camera -->
        <param name="camera_flip"           value="$(arg camera_flip)" />

        <!-- Configuration frame camera -->    
        <param name="pose_frame"                    value="$(arg pose_frame)" />
        <param name="odometry_frame"                value="$(arg odometry_frame)" />
        <param name="base_frame"                    value="$(arg base_frame)" />
        <param name="left_camera_frame"             value="$(arg left_camera_frame)" />
        <param name="left_camera_optical_frame"     value="$(arg left_camera_optical_frame)" />
        <param name="right_camera_frame"            value="$(arg right_camera_frame)" />
        <param name="right_camera_optical_frame"    value="$(arg right_camera_optical_frame)" />
        <param name="imu_frame"                     value="$(arg imu_frame)" />
    
        <!-- SVO file path -->
        <param name="svo_filepath"          value="$(arg svo_file)" />

        <!-- ZED parameters -->
        <param name="zed_id"                value="$(arg zed_id)" />
        <param name="serial_number"         value="$(arg serial_number)" />

        <param name="resolution"            value="$(arg resolution)" />
        <param name="verbose"               value="$(arg verbose)" />
        <param name="mat_resize_factor"     value="1.0" />
        <param name="quality"               value="1" />
        <param name="sensing_mode"          value="0" />
        <param name="frame_rate"            value="$(arg frame_rate)" />
        <param name="odometry_db"           value="" />
        <param name="openni_depth_mode"     value="0" />
        <param name="gpu_id"                value="$(arg gpu_id)" />
        <param name="confidence"            value="100" />
        <param name="gain"                  value="100" />
        <param name="exposure"              value="100" />
        <param name="auto_exposure"         value="true" />
        <param name="depth_stabilization"   value="1" />
        <param name="pose_smoothing"        value="false" />
        <param name="spatial_memory"        value="true" />

        <rosparam param="initial_tracking_pose" subst_value="True">$(arg initial_pose)</rosparam>

        <!-- ROS topic names -->
        <param name="rgb_topic"                 value="$(arg rgb_topic)" />
        <param name="rgb_raw_topic"             value="rgb/image_raw_color" />
        <param name="rgb_cam_info_topic"        value="$(arg rgb_info_topic)" />
        <param name="rgb_cam_info_raw_topic"    value="rgb/camera_info_raw" />

        <param name="left_topic"                value="left/image_rect_color" />
        <param name="left_raw_topic"            value="left/image_raw_color" />
        <param name="left_cam_info_topic"       value="left/camera_info" />
        <param name="left_cam_info_raw_topic"   value="left/camera_info_raw" />

        <param name="right_topic"               value="right/image_rect_color" />
        <param name="right_raw_topic"           value="right/image_raw_color" />
        <param name="right_cam_info_topic"      value="right/camera_info" />
        <param name="right_cam_info_raw_topic"  value="right/camera_info_raw" />

        <param name="depth_topic"               value="$(arg depth_topic)" />
        <param name="depth_cam_info_topic"      value="$(arg depth_cam_info_topic)" />

        <param name="point_cloud_topic"         value="point_cloud/cloud_registered" />        

        <param name="disparity_topic"           value="disparity/disparity_image" />
        <param name="confidence_img_topic"      value="confidence/confidence_image" />
        <param name="confidence_map_topic"      value="confidence/confidence_map" />

        <param name="pose_topic"                value="map" />
        <param name="odometry_topic"            value="odom" />

        <param name="init_odom_with_imu"        value="true" /> <!-- only used with ZED mini -->

        <param name="imu_topic"                 value="imu/data" /> <!-- only used with ZED M -->
        <param name="imu_topic_raw"             value="imu/data_raw" /> <!-- only used with ZED M -->

        <param name="imu_pub_rate"              value="500.0" /> <!-- only used with ZED M -->

    </node>

    <!-- ROS URDF description of the ZED -->
    <group if="$(arg publish_urdf)">
        <param if="$(arg camera_model)" name="zed_description" textfile="$(find zed_wrapper)/urdf/zedm.urdf" />
        <param unless="$(arg camera_model)" name="zed_description" textfile="$(find zed_wrapper)/urdf/zed.urdf" />
        <node name="zed_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher">
            <remap from="robot_description" to="zed_description" />
        </node>
    </group>
        
</launch>
```

---

now the topics published by both the files
first one :

```
    /clock /disparity /left/image_color 
    /left/image_color/compressed   
    /left/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
    /left/image_color/compressedDepth   
    /left/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /left/image_color/theora   
    /left/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions    /left/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
    /left/image_mono   
    /left/image_mono/compressed   
    /left/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
    /left/image_mono/compressedDepth   
    /left/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /left/image_mono/theora   
    /left/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
    /left/image_raw_color/compressed   
    /left/image_rect   
    /left/image_rect/compressed   
    /left/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
    /left/image_rect/compressedDepth   
    /left/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /left/image_rect/theora   
    /left/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
    /left/image_rect_color   
    /left/image_rect_color/compressed   
    /left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
    /left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
    /left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /left/image_rect_color/theora   
    /left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions    /left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates    /points2

  /republish_left/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /republish_left/compressed/parameter_updates
    /republish_right/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /republish_right/compressed/parameter_updates
    /right/image_color   
    /right/image_color/compressed   
    /right/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
    /right/image_color/compressedDepth  
    /right/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /right/image_color/theora   
    /right/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions    /right/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
    /right/image_mono   
    /right/image_mono/compressed   
    /right/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
    /right/image_mono/compressedDepth   
    /right/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /right/image_mono/theora   
    /right/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
    /right/image_raw_color/compressed   
    /right/image_rect   
    /right/image_rect/compressed   
    /right/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
    /right/image_rect/compressedDepth   
    /right/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /right/image_rect/theora   
    /right/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
    /right/image_rect_color   
    /right/image_rect_color/compressed  
    /right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
    /right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
    /right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /right/image_rect_color/theora   
    /right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions    /right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates    /rosout /rosout_agg   
    /rtabmap/global_path   
    /rtabmap/goal_node   
    /rtabmap/goal_reached /rtabmap/info 
    /rtabmap/mapData /rtabmap/odom_info 
    /rtabmap/odom_last_frame   
    /rtabmap/odom_local_map   
    /rtabmap/odom_local_scan_map   
    /stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/compressed
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/compressed/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/compressed/parameter_updates
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/compressedDepth
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/theora
    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/theora/parameter_descriptions    /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle_relay/theora/parameter_updates
    /stereo_camera/left/image_rect   
    /stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color
    /stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle
    /stereo_camera/right/image_raw_throttle_relay
    /stereo_camera/right/image_rect   
    /stereo_image_proc/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_image_proc/parameter_updates
    /stereo_image_proc_debayer_left/parameter_descriptions    /stereo_image_proc_debayer_left/parameter_updates    /stereo_image_proc_debayer_right/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_image_proc_debayer_right/parameter_updates
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_left/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_left/parameter_updates
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_right/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_right/parameter_updates
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_left/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_left/parameter_updates    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_right/parameter_descriptions
    /stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_right/parameter_updates
    /stereo_odometry /tf /tf_static
```

---

nothing is published on these topics

zed_camera.launch topic list :

```
/confidence/confidence_image
/confidence/confidence_image/compressed
/confidence/confidence_image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/confidence/confidence_image/compressed/parameter_updates
/confidence/confidence_image/compressedDepth
/confidence/confidence_image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/confidence/confidence_image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/confidence/confidence_image/theora
/confidence/confidence_image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/confidence/confidence_image/theora/parameter_updates
/confidence/confidence_map
/depth/camera_info
/depth/depth_registered
/depth/depth_registered/compressed
/depth/depth_registered/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/depth/depth_registered/compressed/parameter_updates
/depth/depth_registered/compressedDepth
/depth/depth_registered/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/depth/depth_registered/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/depth/depth_registered/theora
/depth/depth_registered/theora/parameter_descriptions
/depth/depth_registered/theora/parameter_updates
/disparity/disparity_image
/joint_states
/left/camera_info
/left/camera_info_raw
/left/image_raw_color
/left/image_raw_color/compressed
/left/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/left/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/left/image_raw_color/compressedDepth
/left/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/left/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/left/image_raw_color/theora
/left/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/left/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_updates
/left/image_rect_color
/left/image_rect_color/compressed
/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/left/image_rect_color/theora
/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/map
/odom
/point_cloud/cloud_registered
/rgb/camera_info
/rgb/camera_info_raw
/rgb/image_raw_color
/rgb/image_raw_color/compressed
/rgb/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/rgb/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/rgb/image_raw_color/compressedDepth
/rgb/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/rgb/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/rgb/image_raw_color/theora
/rgb/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/rgb/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_updates
/rgb/image_rect_color
/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed
/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/rgb/image_rect_color/theora
/rgb/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/rgb/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/right/camera_info
/right/camera_info_raw
/right/image_raw_color
/right/image_raw_color/compressed
/right/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/right/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/right/image_raw_color/compressedDepth
/right/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/right/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/right/image_raw_color/theora
/right/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/right/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_updates
/right/image_rect_color
/right/image_rect_color/compressed
/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/right/image_rect_color/theora
/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
/zed_wrapper_node/parameter_descriptions
/zed_wrapper_node/parameter_updates
```

---

things are published on these topic, now what do I have to do for a stable 3d map, what am I missing, I am a newbie student.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302407/working-with-stereo-camera-and-rtabmap-for-3d-mapping/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you try this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping) following zed related instructions to see a working example. You can also try [this](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/tree/master/zed_rtabmap_example) zed launch file to start both zed and rtabmap at the same time:

```
$ roslaunch zed_rtabmap_example zed_rtabmap.launch
```

cheers, 
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0